# Sigma algebra associated with sum of random variables

Tags: probability-theory

Let $Y_n$ be iid random varibles with $P(Y_n=-1)=p,$ $P(Y_n = 1) = q$, where $p,q>0$ and $p+q = 1$.

Set $X_0 = 0$ and $X_n = \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$.

If I let $F_n = \sigma(Y_1,Y_2,\dots,Y_n)$, then clearly $X_n$ is measurable with respect to $F_n$, but is it true that $\sigma(X_n) = F_n$?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Lesson: do not accept too soon :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Let $\Omega:=\{\langle1,1\rangle,\langle1,-1\rangle,\langle-1,1\rangle,\langle-1,-1\rangle\}$ and let $\mathcal A:=\wp(\Omega)$. Let $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ be the projections and define a suitable probability $P:\wp(\Omega)\to[0,1]$.

Then $\sigma(Y_1,Y_2)=\wp(\Omega)$.

However $\sigma(X_2)$ does not contain sets like $\{\langle-1,1\rangle\}$ and $\{\langle1,-1\rangle\}$.

This because no Borel-measurable set $A\subseteq\mathbb R$ can be found such that $\{X_2\in A\}=\{\langle-1,1\rangle\}$.

Answer (score 1):

No, but because   $Y_k=X_k-X_{k-1}$ for $k\ge 1$, you have $\sigma(X_1,\ldots,X_n)=\sigma(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)$.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that $\sigma(X_n) \subset \mathscr{F}_n$, as you proved. However, in general $\mathscr{F}_n$ is much bigger than $\sigma(X_n)$. For example, let $n = 2$ and consider the event $E = [\omega: Y_1(\omega) = 1, Y_2(\omega) = -1]$, which belongs to $\mathscr{F}_2$, but it does not belong to $\sigma(X_2)$, since if so, there exists an integer $k$ such that $$E = [\omega: Y_1(\omega) + Y_2(\omega) = k].$$
By the definition of $E$, $k = 0$. Therefore $A = [\omega: Y_1(\omega) = -1, Y_2(\omega) = 1] \subset E$. But on the other hand, $[\omega: Y_1(\omega) = -1, Y_2(\omega) = 1] \cap [\omega: Y_1(\omega) = 1, Y_2(\omega) = -1] = \varnothing.$

Comment: Thank you for crystal clear answer :) I wish I could accept two answers

Comment: btw, is it true that if $E$ is in $F_2$, then $E$ can be written as $E = \cup\{w:Y_1(w) = a_1, Y_2(w) = a_2\}$ for some $a_1,a_2 \in \{0,1\}$?

Comment: No, treat $Z = Y_1 + Y_2$ as an integrate simple random variable. There is a representation theorem to describe what elements in $\sigma(Z)$ should be.